# Caffe training without testing

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I am using [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) to train AlexNet on a known image database. I am benchmarking and want to exclude a testing phase.

Here is the `solver.prototxt` for AlexNet:

```
net: "models/bvlc_alexnet/train_val.prototxt"
test_iter: 1000
test_interval: 1000
base_lr: 0.01
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 100000
display: 20
max_iter: 450000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "models/bvlc_alexnet/caffe_alexnet_train"
solver_mode: GPU
```

While I have never found a definitive doc that detailed all of the prototxt options, comments within Caffe tutorials indicate this "`test_interval`" represents the number of iterations after which we test the trained network.

I figured that I might set it to zero to turn off testing. Nope.

> ```
> F1124 14:42:54.691428 18772 solver.cpp:140] Check failed: param_.test_interval() > 0 (0 vs. 0)
> *** Check failure stack trace: ***
> ```

So I set the `test_interval` to one million, but still of course, Caffe tests the network at iteration zero.

> ```
> I1124 14:59:12.787899 18905 solver.cpp:340] Iteration 0, Testing net (#0)
> I1124 14:59:15.698724 18905 solver.cpp:408]     Test net output #0: accuracy = 0.003
> ```

How do I turn testing off while training?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Caffe's documentation is somewhat scant on details. What I was finally told is this counterintuitive solution:

In your solver.prototxt, take the lines for `test_iter` and `test_interval`

```
test_iter: 1000
test_interval: 1000
```

and simply omit them. If you'd like to prevent the test at the beginning, you would add a line as [@shai suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33909593/1714410):

```
test_initialization: false
```

Comment: 'somewhat scant on details' - that's a vast understatement)

Answer (score 7):

You have a flag for that too. Add

```
test_initialization: false
```

To your `'solver.prototxt'` and you are done ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not prevent testing during traiing.

Comment: @WesModes if you additionally set up otest_interval to be larger than max_iter you should be fine