# Check fail: how to use hdf5 data layer in deep layer?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, hdf5, caffe

I have the train and label data as `data.mat`. (I have 200 training data with 6000 features and labels are (-1, +1) that have saved in data.mat).

I am trying to convert my data (train and test) in `hdf5` and run Caffe using:

```
load input.mat
hdf5write('my_data.h5', '/new_train_x', single( permute(reshape(new_train_x,[200, 6000, 1, 1]),[4:-1:1] ) ));
hdf5write('my_data.h5', '/label_train', single( permute(reshape(label_train,[200, 1, 1, 1]), [4:-1:1] ) ) , 'WriteMode', 'append' );
hdf5write('my_data_test.h5', '/test_x', single( permute(reshape(test_x,[77, 6000, 1, 1]),[4:-1:1] ) ));
hdf5write('my_data_test.h5', '/label_test', single( permute(reshape(label_test,[77, 1, 1, 1]), [4:-1:1] ) ) , 'WriteMode', 'append' );
```

(See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34249025/1714410) regarding converting mat-files to hdf5 in Matlab).

My `train_val.prototxt` is:

```
  layer {
  type: "HDF5Data"
  name: "data"
  top: "new_train_x"     # note: same name as in HDF5
  top: "label_train"     # 
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "file.txt"
    batch_size: 20
  }
  include { phase: TRAIN }
}
layer {
  type: "HDF5Data"
  name: "data"
  top: "test_x"     # note: same name as in HDF5
  top: "label_test"     # 
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "file_test.txt"
    batch_size: 20
  }
  include { phase:TEST }
}

layer {
  name: "ip1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "new_train_x"
  top: "ip1"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 30
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian" # initialize the filters from a Gaussian
      std: 0.01 
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "tanh1"
  type: "TanH"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "tanh1"
}

layer {
  name: "ip2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "tanh1"
  top: "ip2"
  param {
    lr_mult: 1
  }
  param {
    lr_mult: 2
  }
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 1
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian" # initialize the filters from a Gaussian
      std: 0.01 
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "TanH"
  bottom: "ip2"
  bottom: "label_train"
  top: "loss"
}
```

But I have a problem. It seems, it cannot read my input data.

```
I1227 10:27:21.880826  7186 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer data
I1227 10:27:21.880851  7186 net.cpp:110] Creating Layer data
I1227 10:27:21.880866  7186 net.cpp:433] data -> new_train_x
I1227 10:27:21.880893  7186 net.cpp:433] data -> label_train
I1227 10:27:21.880915  7186 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:81] Loading list of HDF5 filenames from: file.txt
I1227 10:27:21.880965  7186 hdf5_data_layer.cpp:95] Number of HDF5 files: 1
I1227 10:27:21.962596  7186 net.cpp:155] Setting up data
I1227 10:27:21.962702  7186 net.cpp:163] Top shape: 20 6000 1 1 (120000)
I1227 10:27:21.962738  7186 net.cpp:163] Top shape: 20 1 1 1 (20)
I1227 10:27:21.962772  7186 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer ip1
I1227 10:27:21.962838  7186 net.cpp:110] Creating Layer ip1
I1227 10:27:21.962873  7186 net.cpp:477] ip1 <- new_train_x
I1227 10:27:21.962918  7186 net.cpp:433] ip1 -> ip1
I1227 10:27:21.979375  7186 net.cpp:155] Setting up ip1
I1227 10:27:21.979434  7186 net.cpp:163] Top shape: 20 30 (600)
I1227 10:27:21.979478  7186 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer tanh1
I1227 10:27:21.979529  7186 net.cpp:110] Creating Layer tanh1
I1227 10:27:21.979557  7186 net.cpp:477] tanh1 <- ip1
I1227 10:27:21.979583  7186 net.cpp:433] tanh1 -> tanh1
I1227 10:27:21.979620  7186 net.cpp:155] Setting up tanh1
I1227 10:27:21.979650  7186 net.cpp:163] Top shape: 20 30 (600)
I1227 10:27:21.979670  7186 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer ip2
I1227 10:27:21.979696  7186 net.cpp:110] Creating Layer ip2
I1227 10:27:21.979720  7186 net.cpp:477] ip2 <- tanh1
I1227 10:27:21.979746  7186 net.cpp:433] ip2 -> ip2
I1227 10:27:21.979796  7186 net.cpp:155] Setting up ip2
I1227 10:27:21.979825  7186 net.cpp:163] Top shape: 20 1 (20)
I1227 10:27:21.979854  7186 layer_factory.hpp:76] Creating layer loss
I1227 10:27:21.979881  7186 net.cpp:110] Creating Layer loss
I1227 10:27:21.979909  7186 net.cpp:477] loss <- ip2
I1227 10:27:21.979931  7186 net.cpp:477] loss <- label_train
I1227 10:27:21.979962  7186 net.cpp:433] loss -> loss
F1227 10:27:21.980006  7186 layer.hpp:374] Check failed: ExactNumBottomBlobs() == bottom.size() (1 vs. 2) TanH Layer takes 1 bottom blob(s) as input.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f44cbc68ea4  (unknown)
    @     0x7f44cbc68deb  (unknown)
    @     0x7f44cbc687bf  (unknown)
    @     0x7f44cbc6ba35  (unknown)
    @     0x7f44cbfd0ba8  caffe::Layer<>::CheckBlobCounts()
    @     0x7f44cbfed9da  caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @     0x7f44cbfef108  caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @     0x7f44cc03f71a  caffe::Solver<>::InitTrainNet()
    @     0x7f44cc040a51  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7f44cc040db9  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @           0x41222d  caffe::GetSolver<>()
    @           0x408ed9  train()
    @           0x406741  main
    @     0x7f44ca997a40  (unknown)
    @           0x406f69  _start
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Now, if i change loss layer like this:

```
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "TanH"
  bottom: "ip2"
  top: "loss"
}
```

I have this problem:

```
F1227 10:53:17.884419  9102 insert_splits.cpp:35] Unknown bottom blob 'new_train_x' (layer 'ip1', bottom index 0)
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @     0x7f502ab5dea4  (unknown)
    @     0x7f502ab5ddeb  (unknown)
    @     0x7f502ab5d7bf  (unknown)
    @     0x7f502ab60a35  (unknown)
    @     0x7f502af1d75b  caffe::InsertSplits()
    @     0x7f502aee19e9  caffe::Net<>::Init()
    @     0x7f502aee4108  caffe::Net<>::Net()
    @     0x7f502af35172  caffe::Solver<>::InitTestNets()
    @     0x7f502af35abd  caffe::Solver<>::Init()
    @     0x7f502af35db9  caffe::Solver<>::Solver()
    @           0x41222d  caffe::GetSolver<>()
    @           0x408ed9  train()
    @           0x406741  main
    @     0x7f502988ca40  (unknown)
    @           0x406f69  _start
    @              (nil)  (unknown)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**Many thanks!!!! Any advice would be appreciated!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data layer is only defined for `phase: TRAIN` I believe the error occurs when caffe attempts to construct the test-time net (i.e., the `phase: TEST` net).
You should have an additional layer with test data:

```
layer {
  type: "HDF5Data"
  name: "data"
  top: "new_train_x"     # note: same name as in HDF5
  top: "label_train"     # 
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "test_file.txt"
    batch_size: 20
  }
  include { phase: TEST } # do not forget TEST phase
}
```

BTW, if you do not want to test your net during training, you can switch this option off. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34387104/1714410) for more information.

---

**Update:**
Forgive me for being blunt, but you are making quite a mess.

1. `"TanH"` is not a loss layer - it's a neuron/activation layer. It serves as a non-linarity applied to a linear layer (conv/inner-product). As such, it accepts a single input (bottom blob) and outputs a single blob (top).
   A loss layer computes a **scalar** loss value and usually requires two inputs: prediction and ground truth to compare to.
2. You did change your net and added a `"HDF5Data"` layer for the `TEST` phase as well, but this layer outputs a `top: "test_x"`, no layer in your net expects a `bottom: "test_x"` you only have layers expecting `"new_train_x"`... same goes for `"label_text"`.

I suggest you re-write your hdf5 files with more generic names (e.g., `x` and `label`) for *both* train and test. Just use different file names to distinguish between them. This way your net works with `"x"` and `"label"` in both phases and only loads the appropriate dataset according to phase.

Comment: I defined TEST phase, but is not working either and i still have the same problem. i  :(

Comment: @ahmadnavidghanizadeh please post your prototxt and entire log

Comment: thanks so much for your time and attention  dear shai.